# Difference between "+=" and normal addition

Tags: c

What is the difference in += and normal add

```
a = a + b;
a += b;
```

what is the different in above two lines?
Is there any increase in CPU cycles for "+=" operator?
Which would be the preferable method of coding.?

Comment: With a good compiler, there shouldn't be any difference (most of the time)

Comment: Most people would go with the second form simply because it's less repetition. Faster to type, easier for humans to parse, and fewer places where you can make a mistake. There are some programming styles, however, which disagree.

Comment: Apart from ilent2's comment, you should always stick to `a+=b;` as it involves less typing.

Comment: @banex you're thinking of C++, but this question is tagged as C. No operator overloading in C.

Comment: The preferred method would be the one that meets the specification. There is a difference between the two, as has been mentioned below, and the one you use will depend on lots of criteria. Don't forget that the expression 'a' might have side effects so the two versions above can yield different results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside single evaluation of first operand, there is second difference, that occurs when `b` is an expression, involving operators with lower precedence. For instance:

```
int a = 1;
a += 0 || 1;
```

yields two, while:

```
int a = 1;
a = a + 0 || 1;
```

stores one into `a`. The equivalent of former statement would be:

```
a = a + (0 || 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference in between them and it is explained in the C standard:

#### C11: 6.5.16.2 Compound assignment (p3):

> Acompound assignment of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to the simple assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)`, except that the lvalue `E1` is evaluated only once, and with respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

When I compile the following two programs,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = 5, b = 10;

  a = a + b;

  return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = 5, b = 10;

  a += b;

  return 0;
}
```

with `gcc file.c -S -O0`, I get the following assembler output (this is just the relevant section)

```
movl  $5, -4(%rbp)                     # Assign 5 to a
movl  $10, -8(%rbp)                    # Assign 10 to b
movl  -8(%rbp), %eax                   # Move b to eax
addl  %eax, -4(%rbp)                   # Add eax to a, store in a
```

This same output is produced with both implementations.

However, although everything works out nicely with integers and a single addition, there are cases where you may get different results, consider for `double a,b` the operation `a *= b*b` and `a = b*a*b`.  If the result of the particular multiplication can't be exactly represented then the two operations will produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

Both the expressions are same. Second one is short hand assignment operator. Which will help us to reduce the reptitive coding.

```
a = a + b; // Here a will come twice.

a += b;
```

Here the repitition of code will be avoided.

Comment: Wrong answer. Both expressions are not same, though both produce same results.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is only in source. The output binary (executable) is exactly the same (with normal current compilers).

You might like one or the other better in different conditions.

I like the short form better, especially when `a` is *complicated*

```
vector[savedpos] = vector[savedpos] + 1000;
vector[savedpos] += 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice) is a good explanation..Quoting from the source

x += y means

- Find the place identified by x
- Add y to it

But x = x + y means:

- Evaluate x+y
- Find the place identified by x
- Copy x into an accumulator
- Add y to the accumulator
- Store the result in x
- Find the place identified by x
- Copy the accumulator to it

Comment: If you are right, then CPU cycles for += take less times than norma add.

Comment: @sujaiMJ - No, the compiler's optimizer knows that they have the same effect, and will remove any difference.

Comment: as mentioned in the answer there `The actual implementation depends on the real instruction set of the processor`..so it may happen